# Python Tkinter with Pyscreenshot script doesn't run after compiling with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, screenshot, pyinstaller

My script runs smoothly. However after compiling with Pyinstaller, launching the .exe  and clicking the start button, the GUI opens once again and crashes.

```
def grabberfunc(*args):
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    savedir=str(mappa)
    savefile="Screenshot_"+str("{:%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S}".format(datetime.datetime.now()))+".png"
    savedirfile=join(savedir,savefile)
    im.save(str(savedirfile))

def scanning():
    interval=deftimeInput.get()
    if running:
        grabberfunc()
    root.after(int(interval)*1000, scanning)

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    ...
```

There is a basic GUI with 2 buttons: 'Start' sets the 'running' variable 'True', the 'Stop' vice versa.
If the script runs the GUI doesn't open up again and runs as I want it to.

Comment: Can you please run the .exe from the command line? This will keep the window open and you will be able to see any errors.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no errors and warnings. The exe runs from the command line, the next prompt appears.
When I click the 'Start' button, the GUI appears again, however there are no warnings.

Comment: If I run the exe in debug, I got exactly the same messages in the command line when the GUI opens again. Might it be in connection with the recursive calling in the 'scanning' function?

Comment: The problem is not the recursion, it's the line calling the pyscreenshot's grab() method. The exe runs well, if this line is omitted. However the purpose of the program is not fulfilled without this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

Instead of importing the `pyscreenshot` module, the `ImageGrab` module should be imported from `PIL`

So the correct import is:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

After compiling the script by `pyinstaller`, the exe runs fine.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I had the exact same problem (python tk + pyscreenshot + pyinstaller), and this solved it.